# Best approach when speaking about concurrency PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update, where-clause

I'm working on php + mysql project where we use a balance column that is used to keep track of a user's balance. Whenever a user makes a purchase their balance gets deducted. However I am trying to figure out what the best way is to tackle multiple requests from the same user when trying to purchase a product.
I've done some research and wrote the following 2 approaches, I don't quite see a difference here could anyone explain what the difference between those 2 approaches is and which one is best regarding concurrency?

```
Approach 1:
START transaction
"SELECT balance from users where user_id = 1 FOR UPDATE"

check if balance - product price is enough then UPDATE
commit

Approach 2:
"UPDATE users set balance = balance - 30 where user_id = 1 AND balance - 30 >= 0"
```

As you can see option 2 is way less code, but I still see a lot of people recommending the first approach (locking the row first and then update).

Could anyone help me understand what actually the difference here is and which one is best to use when you care about concurrency and want to avoid multiple requests possibly making the balance column invalid? If you have better approaches please let me know, maybe I am overthinking the situation. I am using PDO.

Answer (score 1):

Either solution definitively will prevent race conditions. SQL databases have atomicity, consistency, isolation, and durability (ACID) properties. The cool thing about SQL databases: you don't have to worry about race conditions if you get the transactions right.

Single statement operations like the UPDATE in your second example are always atomic transactions. And, the explicit transaction in your (correctly written) first example is also an atomic transaction.

Like @GMB, I prefer to use single statement operations wherever possible. But that's just because the code is easier for the next programmer (or my future self) to understand. Either approach works.

And, if your business rules get more complex, you'll probably need multistatement transactions. That's an advantage of your first approach.

Both your solutions are ACID-preserving.

Comment: Actually, from experience, the first version is easier to understand and follow because it follows the logic of what you or me would do if we were the clercks performing the transaction. The first solution is also easier to debug, since the select is right there in the code, while you would probably write a separate select if you needed to debug the second solution. Nevertheless, I would also pick the second version for this particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

The second approach is the right way to to. That's a single query, that at the same time checks if the user has sufficient founds, and updates their balance.

The database will properly handle concurrency for this query under the hood, as opposed to the first approach, that requires using a transaction to avoid race conditions. The row is locked during the update: if several sessions try to update the same row, the `update`s are execute sequentially, and the changes performed by each query affect the following query.

From your application, you would typically fire the query, and then check whether a row was affected. If yes, then you know the update was executed (so the user had sufficient founds) - else, the transaction was rejected (either because the user does not exists, or because it has insufficient founds).

Comment: So the second approach would be good enough and it would be impossible for 2 queries that happened at the same time to make the balance negative correct?

Comment: @sharpness: yes, that's the point I was trying to make.

Comment: so the database locks the rows when doing the single update or how does that work? In what situation would one use the first approach then?

Comment: @sharpness: the problem with the first solution is that another session might update the same row in between the query that reads it and the one that updates it. That's a race condition, and to avoid it you need a transaction (which locks the row for a longer time). The second approach does not have that problem. That's a single query that does what you want, so the best option here in my opinion.

Comment: The row gets locked in the first approach because I'm using a SELECT FOR UPDATE, this prevents other transactions from updating  and reading the row or am I wrong?

Comment: @sharpness: yes.

Comment: So theres no race condition in the first solution correct? Why do I see alot of people recommending the first approach (select for update) when the second one is easier? Does the first approach offer anything else?

Comment: @sharpness: I don't know. Maybe because that's the first solution that comes to mind...

Comment: Although I agree with the conclusion of this answer, this answer is not entirely accurate. 1) transactions are not used to avoid race conditions, locks are. Transactions only determine the lifespan of row level locks. Transactions are used to ensure that all modifications within them happen or none of them. 2) Both solutions use a transaction, since innodb encapsulates all modifications in a transaction. 3) both solutions use exclusive locks to handle race conditions.